# Can't access any file in subdirectories with Firebase Hosting

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a site hosted in Firebase Hosting and it works fine when I just load content from the current `public` folder. But I can't load anything from a subdir like `/img/logo.png`.

I've searched here and over the internet, but found no working solution. Some similar questions I tried:

[Images not showing up in hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140049/images-not-showing-up-in-hosted-site)

[How to include subdirectories in firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453585/how-to-include-subdirectories-in-firebase-hosting)

---

My includes are like `<script src="js/index.js"></script>`

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
"database": {
 "rules": "database.rules.json"
},
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"headers": [ {
  "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
} ]
}, {
  "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
  "headers" : [ {
  "key" : "Cache-Control",
  "value" : "max-age=7200"
  } ]
}, {
  "source" : "404.html",
  "headers" : [ {
  "key" : "Cache-Control",
  "value" : "max-age=300"
  } ]
} ]

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running `firebase deploy` inside Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

Previously, I was using firebase cli on plain Windows 10.